# Showing a simple function is continuous on a restricted domain

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

**Motivation:** I am studying for an exam over Chapters $1-3$ of *Real Analysis* by Royden and Fitzpatrick, 4th edition. I am stuck on understanding some of Proposition $11$, which I have reproduced below:

**Proposition 11:** Let $f$ be a simple function defined on a set $E$ of finite measure. Then for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and a closed set $F$ contained in $E$ for which $f=g$ on $F$ and $m(E-F)<\varepsilon.$

**Proof:** Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ be the finite number of distinct values taken by $f$, and let them be taken on the sets $E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n,$ respectively. The collection $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ is disjoint since the $a_k$'s are distinct. According to Theorem $11$ of Chapter $2$, we may choose closed sets $F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_n$ such that for each index $k, 1\leq k \leq n,$ $F_k \subseteq E_k$ and $m(E_k-F_k)<\varepsilon/n.$ Define $g$ on $F$ to take the value $a_k$ on $F_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n.$ Since the collection $\{F_k\}_{k=1}^{n}$ is disjoint, $g$ is properly defined.

> Moreover, $g$ is continuous on $F$ since for a point $x \in F_i,$
>   there is an open interval containing $x$ which is disjoint from the closed set $\cup_{k \neq i} F_k$ and  hence on the intersection of this interval with $F$ the function $g$
>   is constant.

But $g$ can be extended from a continuous function on the closed set $F$ to a continuous function on all of $\mathbb{R}.$ The continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ has the required approximation properties.

**Question:** Please explain rigorously why the "grey" area is true?

Comment: What is $E$? That seems to be missing here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See edit..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement $Z$ of $\cup_{k \neq i} F_k$ is open since the $F_k$ are closed, and so if you take a point $ x \in F_i$ (which is in $Z$) then since $Z$ is open you can find an open neighborhood around $x$ which is contained in $Z$. Then the only value the function $g$ can take in this neighborhood is the value on $F_i$, so $g$ is constant.

Comment: How does this show continuity of $g$, again ? I understand that $g$ is constant on each $F_i$. But why does it have to be constant on $F$